# Try to load and start 'EFI\Boot\bootx64.efi' from UEFI code of a DXE

Tags: operating-system, driver, uefi, loadimage

Good day, dear colleagues!
I am having the following problem.

I'm trying to launch the OS from my own DXE-module through efi-loader.
My DXE-module starts at the moment BSD-phase, when READY_TO_BOOT events is occurred.
I correctly get the path to the efi-loader (in fact, I manually select this file from the file browser implemented in DXE-module so that the path is exactly correct):
\EFI\Boot\BOOTX64.efi

Then I call the LoadImage() function and get file handler:

```
bs->LoadImage(TRUE, imageHandle, path_to_efi_loader, NULL, NULL, &fileHandler);
```

Then I call the StartImage() function:

```
bs->StartImage(fileHandler, &exitSize, &exitData)
```

However, after launching the efi-loader, an attempt is made to start the Windows OS and an error window is displayed:

[Windows recovery screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gdptv.jpg)

Those, the path to the efi-loader is passed correctly, the loading and launch is performed correctly, but is there some error in the launch environment?

I tried first to load the efi-loader into memory by passing the buffer to it in LoadImage().
Also, between LoadImage() and StartImage(), I tried to get EFI_LOADED_IMAGE_PROTOCOL for the efi-loader and reset its ParentHandle.

It didn't help either.

What could be the problem here?

Thank you!

I expected the OS Windows to start.
However, OS Windows recovery message occurred.